# Conditional return url in channel form

Tags: safecracker

I have a channel form with and i need ti to have a different return url based on how they answer one of the questions in the form.

If they select yes it should redirect to URLA
if they select no it should redirect to URLB

I tried swaping out the hidden "return_url" input but that doesnt seem to do it, any suggestions?

Comment: How have you tried "swapping out" the hidden return_url?

Comment: Yes thanks, I mentioned that in my question.  Tried it but it didn't work

Comment: No, I asked "How" - what did you do/try?

Comment: Just used some jquery